# The ring of fractions $K(x)$ is the field generated by $K$ and $x$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, galois-theory, algebraic-curves

I would like to show that the ring of fractions $K(x)$ of $K[x]$ in an extension $L$, where $K\subset L$ fields, is the field generated by $K$ and $x$ (let's call it by $\tilde{K(x)}$).

I know just the $\tilde {K(x)}\subset K(x)$, I need help in the reverse implication.

I need help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your definition of generated ? Is division allowed ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus $\tilde {K(u)}$ is the subfield of $L$ generated by $K$ and $u$

Comment: generated how ? addition multiplication and division ?

Comment: oh I see it has to be a field. So it is closed under those operations, so its clear that $K(x)$ can be obtained.

Comment: Is $x\in L$? $K[x]$? I'm very confused by your notation - usually, $x$ is an indeterminate, and if $x\in L$, then $K[x]$ is already a field unless $x$ is transcendental over $K$.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus $L$ is the field extension of $K$

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you're defining $\widetilde{K(u)}$ as follows. Given a field extension $K \subset L$ and $u \in L$, then $\widetilde{K(u)}$ is by definition the set of all elements of $L$ obtainable by some finite sequence of additions, multiplications, and divisions involving constants from $K$ and $u$.

In that case, to get the reverse implication for $\widetilde{K(x)} = K(x)$, pick some $p(x)/q(x) \in K(x)$ as usual and note that it can be obtained by some finite sequence of additions, multiplications, and divisions involving constants from $K$ and $u$. (I don't think any version of this question can be much less trivial.)